# ImportError: relocation error: R_AMD64_32: /scipy-1.6.2-py3.7-solaris-2.11-i86pc.64bit.egg/scipy/spatial/qhull.cpython-37m.so: symbol (unknown)

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, solaris, sunos

I am trying to run my code in Solaris environment with Python 3.7.4 [GCC 7.3.0] on sunos5. When importing necessary libraries `from scipy import stats` I face this issue. Does anybody know how can I fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a library linking issue. Try the following, as it may need re-installing, or updated:

pip install pyhull

If that doesn't work, you may have to recompile python, and any additional libraries or utilities (coreutils, binutils, glibc, even gcc).

If you have the Oracle C compiler, you can try that by using cc, or gcc if that is easier. The Oracle C compiler would be specific to your Solaris installation and may work better.

If you do not want to do that, you might want to try a packaged version of python for your version of SunOS / Solaris and then install pyhull or qhull using pip.